# Hybris hotfolder import "pause"

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hotfolder

Is there any workaround in **Hybris** for **hotfolders** to be **paused** manually?
Here is the story and the problem: In production we have 2 data import servers for our application. Both servers use the same shared hotfolder for multiple different hotfolder configurations, and thus importing several different incoming files day by day. Our production deployment for these servers are differ from the other (non data import) servers of the application, because we have to wait for these servers to finish the actual in process file import, so we have to manually check the /processing folder over and over again 'till there isn't any file. Our goal is to skip this manual process, instead just "tell" the Hybris to stop the processing after the currently in progress imports.
Is there any OOTB implementation to do this?

Comment: Are you able to leverage JMX? If you can, I think there's a way to stop the channels via JMX. You can check this webinar for more information https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TetfR7ULnA8 but the idea is that there is already some MBean functionality that exposes statistics and operations over all of the spring-integration elements.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no there is not. You can probably fix your issue by creating a temporary "work in progress" file while the import starts then you delete the file when it ends. You can then automize the manual check with a method that check if there is a "work in progress" file.